# Group grep results by the searched patterns

Tags: grep

I am trying to group the search result by the patterns that I am searching after, but I can only get to results by files.

This is the closest I got:

`grep -orE "btn-gray|btn-outline-white" ../../front/src/components  | uniq -c`

Which gives me this result:

```
   8 ../../front/src/components/UI/Demo/RzDemoButtons.vue:btn-outline-white
   4 ../../front/src/components/UI/Demo/RzDemoTabs.vue:btn-outline-white
   1 ../../front/src/components/UI/Elements/Filters/RzFilter.vue:btn-outline-white
   1 ../../front/src/components/MessagingCenter/MessageDetails/DetailsEmail.vue:btn-gray
   4 ../../front/src/components/MessagingCenter/MessageDetails/DetailsEmail.vue:btn-outline-white
```

But I would need a result like:

```
btn-gray::8
btn-outline-white::13
```

Comment: How do you get the `8`?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Replace `|` with `| sort `?

Comment: @Cyrus I got the `8, 4, 1`, etc. with the query I pasted to the question, with the number of results at the beginning of the rows. Adding `sort` just sorts the result, but does not change the output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done via `awk`, I'm not sure so please test it and let me know the result!

```
grep -orE "btn-gray|btn-outline-white" ../../front/src/components | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "::" $1}'
```

desired result :

```
btn-gray::1
btn-outline-white::13
```

Comment: This works nicely, however, a few things have changed since I asked my question, and I was wondering if the result could be changed to an array of objects, something like `[{'btn-gray': 1}, {'btn-outline-white': 13}]`?

Comment: Please create a new topic and ask your question there in full detail, then share the link to the new topic here. I will definitely check it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531464/group-grep-results-by-the-searched-patterns-into-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 2):

This would probably do what you want.  It's incrementing the value in a dictionary (%c) keyed by matching strings, then printing the match count at the end:

```
perl -lne '$c{$1}++ if /(btn-gray|btn-outline-white)/ }{ print "$_\::$c{$_}" for keys %c' \
$(find ../../front/src/components -type f)
```

Strings with zero count would be omitted.

HTH.   I am reluctant to include perl answers on the sed/awk/grep questions because they get malicious downvotes.  But I can't help myself... you want a dictionary aka hash. If you'd like me to invest more time explaining this, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful solution you provided,I actually really like Perl too, God bless you, my friend, 1++

Comment: NP.   Perl in stream processing mode (`perl -p` or `perl -n`) is super handy if you already know perl.  `-l` does chomp on read, adds linebreak on write.  `-n` suppresses print.  `}{` (eskimo kiss) is less clear than `END{ .. }`   Keep in mind that perl supports anything you can do in sed or awk, though solutions are less well documented.

Comment: check this nice method with perl  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246585/efficient-use-of-sed-in-replacing-non-zero-with-true-and-zero-with-false/77248905#77248905

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
grep -orE "btn-gray|btn-outline-white" ../../front/src/components | sed 's#.*:##' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
      1 btn-gray
     17 btn-outline-white
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `sed 's#.*:##'` does exactly?

Comment: The regex `.*:` matches characters from the start of the string till the rightmost `:` character in the string. Then the matched portion is removed. As a result, the substring after `:` is extracted.