# Group grep results by the searched patterns into an array of objects

Tags: php, grep

In PHP I am searching and counting all the use cases of some classes in almost all files, with `grep`.

```php
\exec("grep -orE '" . $classesBarred . "' ../../front/src/components | sort | uniq -c", $allClassesCount);
```

Where `$classesBarred` contains a string of classes like `search-unfocused|bg-app|enlarged-window` (but much more).

The current result is

```
'      2 ../../front/src/components/Actions/ActionOwner.vue:show', 
'      1 ../../front/src/components/Actions/ActionOwner.vue:action', 
'      1 ../../front/src/components/Actions/ActionOwner.vue:show', 
'      5 ../../front/src/components/Actions/ActionOwner.vue:action', 
'      1 ../../front/src/components/Actions/ActionOwner.vue:show',
.... (plus a few hundred more lines like these)
```

I would need the result in an array, something like:

```
[
  {show: 38}, {action: 123}, {search-unfocused: 90}, {....}
]
```

**EDIT:**
@Freeman provided a solution to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76510014/group-grep-results-by-the-searched-patterns), using `awk`

`grep -orE "btn-gray|btn-outline-white" ../../front/src/components | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "::" $1}'`

which gave this result:

```
btn-gray::1
btn-outline-white::13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes as I can see, your code uses `awk` to rearrange output from `grep` into two columns, one is class name, and two contains the count,
the the output is like this :

```
search-unfocused 90
bg-app 5
enlarged-window 12
```

now you can easily, parse this output into an array by PHP like this :

```
$results = array();
foreach ($allClassesCount as $line) {
  $parts = explode(" ", $line);
  $className = $parts[0];
  $count = (int)$parts[1];
  if (!isset($results[$className])) {
    $results[$className] = $count;
  } else {
    $results[$className] += $count;
  }
}
```

and the array result is like below :

```
[
  "search-unfocused" => 90,
  "bg-app" => 5,
  "enlarged-window" => 12,
  ...
]
```

**Update :**
If you insist on using awk and sed, you can do it like this:

```
grep -orE "$classesBarred" ../../front/src/components | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print "{\""$2"\": "$1"},"}' | paste -sd '' | sed 's/,$//' | awk '{print "["$0"]"}'
```

and the result is like this :

```
[
  {"show": 38},
  {"action": 123},
  {"search-unfocused": 90},
  {....}
]
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping for a solution using `awk` or `sed` or something similar

Comment: @MagorMenessy I also wrote it for you using awk and sed and updated the answer. I couldn't test it, so please test it yourself and let me know the result. Also, if you got the answer to your question, I would appreciate it if you confirm it so that the topic can be closed. Good luck my friend!

Comment: I'm actually glad you did PHP solution.   I'd thrown perl in the mix in a prior, less specified, version of this question, saying "I know people dislike perl, but it seems like you want a dictionary (key/value pairs)."   Sure looks like you are using a dict in PHP which makes a ton of sense.

Comment: In my question, I mentioned PHP because I was hoping for a solution directly within `exec` ^^, as I had a great deal of time just figuring out how to adjust the double and simple quotations before. I think I'll just go with the PHP parsing. Thanks!