# efficient use of sed in replacing non zero with true and zero with false

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Team,
i have a file that looks for non zero and replaces with FALSE and 0 with TRUE. am doing it like this

sample input text

```
branch="false" hits="0" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="1" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="2" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="211" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="411" lineNumber="36"
```

```
sed -i   '/<line/s/hits="0"/hits="false"/g' $coverage_file
sed -i   '/<line/s/hits="1"/hits="true"/g' $coverage_file
sed -i   '/<line/s/hits="2"/hits="true"/g' $coverage_file
sed -i   '/<line/s/hits="3"/hits="true"/g' $coverage_file
```

can i combine all these in less operations?

expected outout

```
branch="false" hists="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
```

Comment: Combine last 3 commands into one: `sed -i   '/<line/s/hits="[123]"/hits="true"/g' $coverage_file`

Comment: thanks a lot.hope that `123` is `1` or `2` or `3` or `any` I have a follow up case, what if that digit is non-zero and non-single digit?

Comment: In the general case - there's also command grouping with braces e.g. `/<line/{ s///; s///; }`

Comment: BTW, using XML-unaware tools to edit XML files is bad practice in general; it's much less bug-prone to use something like a Python or Perl XML library that can actually parse the file format and understands comments, namespaces, CDATA sections, and all the other relevant complexities.

Comment: included sample output and input

Comment: thanks for the sample input and expected output but, they don't match your sample code; the code is looking for the string `<line` but no such string exists in the sample data

Comment: xml parser tools would work with a condition that the file is proper xm format. here my file is corrupted xml and no tool will be able to format it. hence we first need to fix it up using alternate tools such as sed and awk then use xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten along these lines:

```bash
sed -E -i '
    /<line/ {
        s/(hits=")0"/\1false"/g
        s/(hits=")[^"]*[1-9][^"]*"/\1true"/g
    }
' "$coverage_file"
```

This calls sed just once, combines the conditions for "true", and uses capture groups.

Comment: [Sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246585/efficient-use-of-sed-in-replacing-non-zero-with-true-and-zero-with-false#comment136180921_77246585) the OP really needs `.*[^0].*` instead of `[1-3]`.

Comment: that is correct but with your expression, rest of the line is also getting deleted which comes after the numbers. How can i stop right after number ends?

Comment: included sample output and input

Comment: Change `.*[^0].*` to `[^"]*[1-9][^"]*`. You don't NEED to change `^0` to `1-9` but I'm just getting rid of one negative to make it clearer.

Comment: it is doing good for all cases but not replacing 0 with FALSE. i want 0 to be false and rest all digits to be true. your expression is skipping 0 alone and doing rest. how to do 0?

Comment: output to answer: `command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: There is no command `a` in the script in this answer so you're not doing what it shows in this answer if you're getting that error message about `command a`.

Comment: you are correct. sorry my bad. it works.

Answer (score 2):

You only have two options, "0" or something else.
First replace the 0, all remaining digits will be true.

```
sed 's/hits="0"/hits="false"/;s/hits="[0-9]*"/hits="true"/' file
```

The same idea with `awk`:

```
 awk '{ $2=sprintf("hits=\"%s\"", match($2,/"0"/) ? "false" : "true") } 1' file
```

Comment: tested sed. works cool

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `gnu-sed` solution using `/e` flag:

```bash
# define a function in bash
repl() { local s; (( $2 )) && s=true || s=false; echo "${1}$s${3}"; }

# export the function
export -f repl

# use it in single gnu-sed command
sed -i -E "s/(.* hits=\")([^\"]+)(\".*)/repl '\1' '\2' '\3'/e" file

# check changed file
cat file

branch="false" hits="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {$4=($4 ? "true" : "false")} 1' file
branch="false" hits="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
```

Add `-i inplace` with GNU awk to change the input file or append `> tmp && mv tmp file` with any other awk.

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve this with `Perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(hits=")(\d+)(")/$1.($2 ? "true" : "false").$3/ge' file
```

output :

```
branch="false" hits="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way assuming every line actually has correct hits entry let `file.txt` content be

```
branch="false" hits="0" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="1" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="2" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="211" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="411" lineNumber="36"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="hits=\""}{sub(/^[[:digit:]]+/,$2+0?"true":"false",$2);print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
branch="false" hits="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `AWK` to treat `hits="` as field separator then instruct to replace leading digits in 2nd field by `true` if number is non-zero and `false` otherwise, observe that I add zero to provoke GNU `AWK` to treat field as number, which lead to finding longest prefix constituting legal number.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Yet another awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]+/,(match($2,/[1-9]/)?"true":"false"),$2)}1' file
```

Output:

```
branch="false" hits="false" lineNumber="36"
branch="false" hits="true" lineNumber="36"
...
```